# Reference: Asymptotic analysis in probability theory

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, asymptotics, book-recommendation

I am from physics background. I want to learn "limit theorems in probability theory". So recently I started reading some books. But I realize a need to get used to with asymptotic analysis. I know that asymptotic analysis in huge field and I don't want to learn everything. I want to get skillful in only small part of asymptotic analysis which will be helpful in realizing probability limit theorems.

So the question is, What are the references (books, online-notes, etc.) for that?

Comment: It all depends on how rigorous you would like to be. Serious asymptotic analysis requires knowledge of measure theory.

Comment: I am working on a physics problem and right now some part of it become a complex probability theory problem where I have defined a quantity which is sum of large number of dependent random variables where each variable is linear transformed form of binomial random variable. I realize that, sooner or later I will have to do some serious mathematical calculations which will be some variant of some general form of 'central limit theorem'. Hence I thing, my level of interest in asymptotic analysis will be of moderate level, not too abstract mathematical and also not too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis* by De Bruijn? From the preface:

> "[The book's] purpose is to teach asymptotic methods by explaining a number of examples in every detail, so as to suit beginners who seriously want to acquire some technique in attacking asymptotic problems."
>
> [...]
>
> "This book has not been written exclusively for mathematicians, but also for those physicists and engineers who have a certain maturity with respect to analysis, including some general knowledge of complex function theory."

Comment: Isn't this book about asymptotic expansions (of sequences, functions, power series, you name it) using $o,O$ notations ? I don't remember seeing anything probabilistic in there.